# ICMPv6 not reachable under Windows 10 while under Linux it is fine, why, how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, networking, ipv6, icmp

I have just upgraded my ISP and it is finally **IPv6-capable**. Last year I had an ISP not capable, so... The only thing which does not seem to work under Windows only, is ICMPv6. Since it's an online test, one can presume maybe only `ping6` (***echo** request / reply* to be exact). But I am not exactly networking guy.

---

### IPv6 online test

I personally used: https://ipv6-test.com/

---

### Results under Linux (Mint 19)

[image: ipv6-test.com - results under Linux]

### Results under Windows (10)

Varies only in the ICMP field where it says **Filtered** under Windows, instead of **Reachable** under Linux, which is my desired outcome.

---

As a Linux guy, I don't get to boot Windows often, but still, I'd like to investigate if all of ICMP is blocked by standard Windows firewall, or only the ***echo** request / reply*. At the moment of writing this question to my text book, I don't have many ideas what can be wrong and how to fix that.

---

What I've tried: Opening Advanced Windows Firewall, sorted all ICMPv6 lines, found the ***echo** request + reply* rules, looked into their settings, it seemed fine on a quick look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have installed and opened the Wireshark software on my Linux.

Side note: After a few minutes of not being able to look at my WLAN interface, I realized I need to be added to `wireshark` group with, and re-login afterward:

```
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark username
```

Back to the Wireshark, closing all visible applications, filtering only IPv6 traffic I found this after re-loading the test page:

[image: Wireshark - IPv6 traffic - test found to use only echo request + reply]

---

Basically the results told me the online test found to use only ***echo** request + reply*.

---

So, I went to Advanced Windows Firewall, sorted all ICMPv6 lines again and this time I noticed, possibly by default, both the ***echo** request + reply* were just not Enabled, corrected by right clicking the rule and click on Enable. If you want to be *pingable* on IPv6 network, which might be opinion-based if to do so or not, so I myself do want to be.

---

Finally, you need to enable both the input, and output rules. I originally did a mistake of enabling only the Inbound rules, so be aware of that.